# Clear input field: undefined method `clear' for #<Watir::Input:XYZ> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am not sure why I can not `clear` my input field.

**PageObject**:

```
element(:test_input_field) { |b| b.input(class: "search-field") }

def set_search_value(search_entry)
  test_input_field.when_present.clear
  test_input_field.when_present.set(search_entry)
end
```

**Step_file**:

```
page.set_search_value(search_entry)
```

**Output**:

```
undefined method `clear' for #'<'Watir::Input:0x00000003980d20'>' (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I think set also clear the old value before setting new value, so can remove this line `test_input_field.when_present.clear` and try..

Comment: kk yea true, but for me was more important why clear and input not work together :)

Comment: So this has already answered by Justin Ko..need to follow his answer..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clear` (and `set`) method are not defined for generic input elements - ie `Watir::Input`. They are only defined for the specific input types - text field, checkbox, etc.

To make the code work, you would need to convert the `input` into the more specific type, which is likely a text field. You can do this using the `to_subtype` method:

```
test_input_field.when_present.to_subtype.clear
test_input_field.when_present.to_subtype.set(search_entry)
```

As @SaurabhGaur mentions, `set` already starts by clearing the existing value, so you could just do:

```
test_input_field.when_present.to_subtype.set(search_entry)
```

Unless the `input` type changes, it would make more sense to define the element as a `text_field` so you do not need to convert it. It might depend on which page object library you are using, but I would expect you could do:

```
element(:test_input_field) { |b| b.text_field(class: "search-field") }

def set_search_value(search_entry)
  test_input_field.when_present.clear
  test_input_field.when_present.set(search_entry)
end
```

Comment: Never heard about .to_subtype, interesting.
Yea the text_field was doing fine now.
So .clear seems not to work on a general input.
thx

Comment: The problem with `clear` and `set` is that they need to functionally do different things based on the input type. For example, clearing a checkbox needs to do a click where as clearing a text field means selecting the text and hitting the delete button. As a result, it only makes sense to implement the methods for the specific input types and not the general input.